# How do you translate "across a crowded room" into German?

Tags: word-usage

I used "in der Grosser Menschen Menge."

The context is another one of my translations, of ["Some Enchanted Evening" (Rogers and Hammerstein)](http://www.stlyrics.com/lyrics/southpacific/someenchantedevening.htm)

> Ein bezauberdes Abend. 
>   Siehst du eine Fremde, 
>   Siehst du eine Fremde, 
>   In der grosser Menschenmenge.

Comment: For these poetry translations, it would be good to know what you are trying to accomplish. Do you just want to convey the original meaning, so you could translate the text literally? Do you want to be able to sing it, so you need to preserve the syllable counts, assonance and other poetic devices?

Comment: @Tim N:I want to produce a usable version of poetry in reasonably authentic German, with more or less the same syllabification as the original.

Comment: At least *in der großen Menschenmenge* — große*n*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the goal is to produce something poetic while keeping as close as possible to the original syllable count, I would go for

```
Eines Abends voll Magie,
siehst du eine Fremde,
siehst du eine Fremde
inmitten der Menge.
Irgendwie weisst du,
weisst du schon dann,
dass du sie wiedersehn wirst
wieder und wieder.
```

However, this looses quite a bit of information (e.g. that events are taking place indoors).

My attempt at translating the entire thing as accurately as possible, and entirely ignoring the syllable count:

```
Eines verzauberten Abends,
siehst du vielleicht eine Unbekannte,
siehst du vielleicht eine Unbekannte
über das Gedränge hinweg
am anderen Ende des Raums.
Und irgendwie weisst du,
weisst du es schon dann,
dass du sie irgendwo wiedersehen wirst –
wieder und wieder.

Eines verzauberten Abends,
lacht vielleicht jemand.
Hörst du vielleicht sie lachen
über das Gedränge hinweg
am anderen Ende des Raums.
Und Nacht für Nacht,
so seltsam das scheint,
wird der Klang ihres Lachens
in deinen Träumen singen.

Wer kann das erklären?
Wer kann dir sagen warum?
Narren geben dir Gründe,
Weise versuchen es nicht einmal.

Eines verzauberten Abends,
wenn du deine wahre Liebe findest,
wenn du sie dich rufen fühlst,
über das Gedränge hinweg
am anderen Ende des Raums
dann flieg an ihre Seite,
und mach sie dein.
Sonst wirst du dein Leben lang
ganz alleine träumen.

Wenn du sie gefunden hast,
lass sie niemals los.
Wenn du sie gefunden hast,
lass sie niemals los.
```

Answer (score 3):

I would translate it as

> Ein bezaubernder Abend.
>   Siehst du die Fremde,
>   Siehst du die Fremde,
>   Im Gedränge.

From the context it is clear that it refers to a dedicated stranger, therefore I changed *eine* to *die*.

**Edit:** Somehow the situation reminds me of [Edith Piaf — La Foule](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2UlEJXkxnSc) .

Comment: @bernd: No, I don't think they met before. So I wouldn't call it a "dedicated" stranger. But good to know for the OTHER situation.

Comment: In a crowd, there are almost always some strangers. When there is a songle one toughing your fantasy, you have to use `die`.

Comment: @Hendrik Danke, ja ein verzauberter Abend ist auch OK.

Comment: @bernd: How about "Siehst du dieser Fremde" to keep it two syllables?

Comment: @Tom you can say `Siehst du diesen Fremden` or `Siehst du diese Fremde` depending on gender.

Comment: I would translate the first line with: `Eines bezaubernden Abends`, it follows the english version more closely, I think. Also, maybe: `Eines verzaubernden Abends` ?

Comment: Que d'érudition et de sensibilité dans ce rapprochement avec Piaf, bernd! Und vielen Dank für den Link.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my suggestion for a translations of these lyrics:

> Eines wunderschönen Abends
>
> wirst Du vielleicht einer Fremden begegnen
>
> am andern Ende eines dicht gefüllten Raumes

If you need to take care of the melody you may catch the sense with something like

> Eines schönen Abends
>
> steht eine Fremde da
>
> inmitten aller Leute

Comment: I think it would be hard to sing when the translation is twice the length of the original.

Comment: tried with a shorter version (but the shortage cuts out a lot of atmosphere)

Answer (score 2):

Mein Vorschlag:

> An einem verzauberten Abend
>   Wirst du vielleicht eine Fremde sehen
>   Am anderen Ende des überfüllten Saales

Comment: Abend und "verzaubert" will mir nicht so recht passen (klingt vielleicht zu sehr nach Magiervorstellung).

Comment: @Takkat das Original "enchanted" (nicht *enchanting*) will aber genau das ausdrücken; du bist einfach kein Romantiker. ;-)

Comment: Romantik ist mir schon immer abgegangen! Mir ist plötzlich ein Kaninchen aus dem Zylinder entgegengesprungen, und dann war's auch schon vorbei mit dem "Zauber" :D. *Enchanted* und "verzaubert" passt schon.